# backbone.js - list with 3 items per list item

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a list (`<ul></ul>`) on my page that I'd like to model as a backbone.js collection. Let's call the model Animal and then I have an Animals collection and an AnimalView. Now for each list item I have, instead of one animal, three animals. So something like:

- animal1, animal2, animal3
- animal4, animal5, animal6

Now my question is what would be the correct way of doing that in backbone.js? I can have three animals in each model but that feels wrong.

Comment: Not as far as I can tell. But anyway, I was being stupid. The partitioning belongs in the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest collections inside other collections without any problems

```
var Animal = Backbone.Model.extend();
var Cage = Backbone.Collection.extend({model: Animal});
var Zoo = Backbone.Collection.extend({collection: Cage});

new Zoo([ 
    new Cage([
        new Animal(), 
        new Animal()
    ]), 
    new Cage([
        new Animal(), 
        new Animal()
    ])
]);
```

Comment: Are you sure about it? Why did you specify collection attribute in parameters for Zoo class? I can't find this behavior in Backbone source